# How to pass several columns from a DataFrame all together in Word2Vec

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, vectorization, word2vec

While using Word2Vec algorithm, how to pass several text columns from a pandas data frame all together for the model to train.

Image showing columns present in DataFrame][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/80iiq.png

'task' is the name of the dataframe.

**Code is as follows:**

import gensim
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities

model_taskname = gensim.models.Word2Vec(task.iloc[:,0], min_count=1, size = 32, window = 10, sg=1)
model_elementname = gensim.models.Word2Vec(task.iloc[:,1], min_count=1, size = 32, window = 10, sg=1)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec), you can pass a list of lists of tokens. That means, it would look like `[[token, token, ...], [token, token, ...], ...]` which is of the shape `(N, 1)`.

Now, since you have several columns, you have a few solutions to try:

1. Not considering class column, having a feature dataset with the shape `(N, K)`, merge K into 1 - `(N, 1)`. That is, `[1], [2], [3]]` -> `[[1, 2, 3]]`. Risks? You might lose the context. Run some tests and see how it performs.
2. Create several models, that would take each of the columns separately. Then train the prediction model with each of them separately, and compare the metrics. That will give you an idea which feature gives you better results.